# Odoo Client Error Error: QWeb2: Template 'mail.chat.MessagingMenu' not found

Tags: odoo-10

When I trying to upgrade my application error occurs.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiYMW.png)
What is the Solution for it ??

I can't able to fix this error .
Plz give me the solution ...

Comment: Is the app which contains MessagingMenu already installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, make sure that:

- The user 'odoo' is the owner of your DB. In any case:
  `ALTER DATABASE <db_name> OWNER TO odoo;`
- You have all the dependencies installed, in particular **less**. In any case:
  `sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css`

Comment: Changing the database owner was the solution to my problem, which occurred after restoring the database to a new machine.

Comment: exactly my case: 'restoring the database'. Thanks!